# How do I remove the limit of a limitTo filter on mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects called `articles` each of which contains an array of strings called `category`. Each article is represented in the DOM with an `ngRepeat` directive which contains a second `ngRepeat` directive to represent each category. The second `ngRepeat` has a `limitTo` filter that limits the number of categories to 2. When the user mouses over the base `article` element the limit should be removed and all strings in the `category` array should be visible.

My problem is that when a user mouses over one element the full array of categories for every object in the `articles` array is revealed. How can I get the DOM to reveal only the full categories for the element the mouse event takes place on?

`Plunkr:` https://plnkr.co/edit/PW51BBnQEv589rIdnaCK?p=preview

Comment: You can have ng-if inside of ng-repeat to check as condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your article on which you hover and set in a `scope` variable. Than simply update your `ng-if` check to :

```
ng-if="hoverMode === true && hoveredArticle === article"
```

**Working example :**

```js
// Code goes here

angular
 .module('myApp', [])
 .controller('myController', ($scope) => {
   
   $scope.articles = [ { date: 'some', category: [ {name: "Sports"}, {name: "News"}, {name: "Cinema"} ] }, { date: 'some', category: [ {name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"} ] }, { date: 'some', category: [ {name: "D"}, {name: "E"}, {name: "F"} ] } ]
 
  $scope.hoverMode = false;

  $scope.showAllcat = function(article) {
   $scope.hoveredArticle = article;
   $scope.hoverMode = true;
  }
  
  $scope.hideAllcat = function() {
   $scope.hoveredArticle = null;
   console.log('hover working');
   $scope.hoverMode = false;
  }
 
 
 
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="script.ts"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="system.config.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="tsconfig.json"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='myController'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Categories</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="article in articles">
        <td><span>{{ article.date }}</span></td>
        <td ng-if="hoverMode === false || hoveredArticle !== article">
            <span ng-repeat="cat in article.category | limitTo: 2">&nbsp;
                <span class="label label-warning"
                      ng-mouseover="showAllcat(article)">{{ cat.name}}
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td ng-if="hoverMode === true && hoveredArticle === article">
            <span ng-repeat="cat in article.category">&nbsp;
                <span class="label label-warning"
                      ng-mouseleave="hideAllcat()">{{ cat.name}}
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way this can be approached. I removed the `ng-if` directive as it is not needed. In your first `ng-repeat` directive the article object is available in the scope to be used. `$scope.hoverMode` was removed in favor of adding an attr to each article called `limit`.

The `ng-mouseover` event i replaced in favor of `ng-mouseenter` as it is the parallel event to `ng-mouseleave`. Instead of having these directives call a function, the limit value is manipulated via a simple expression in the DOM. 
I left the function `showAllCat()` in the code with modifications. It takes an article object as a parameter to manipulate the category directly.

If the `limit` var is `undefined`, then there is no limit constraint in the filter.

By removing `ng-if` you're removing n number of listeners equivalent to the number of articles. Since it wasn't needed, that's just extra overhead.

```js
// Code goes here

angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ($scope) => {
    $scope.minLimit = 2;
    $scope.maxLimit = undefined;

    $scope.articles = [{
      date: 'some',
      category: [{
        name: "Sports"
      }, {
        name: "News"
      }, {
        name: "Cinema"
      }]
    }, {
      date: 'some',
      category: [{
        name: "A"
      }, {
        name: "B"
      }, {
        name: "C"
      }]
    }, {
      date: 'some',
      category: [{
        name: "D"
      }, {
        name: "E"
      }, {
        name: "F"
      }]
    }];
    $scope.articles.forEach((article)=>{article.limit=$scope.minLimit});
    
    $scope.showAllcat = function(article) {
      console.log('hover working');
      article.limit = article.limit === minLimit ? maxLimit : minLimit;
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="script.ts"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="system.config.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="tsconfig.json"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='myController'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Categories</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="article in articles"
          ng-mouseenter="article.limit = maxLimit"
          ng-mouseleave="article.limit = minLimit">
        <td><span>{{ article.date }}</span></td>
        <td><span ng-repeat="cat in article.category | limitTo: article.limit">&nbsp;
                <span class="label label-warning">{{cat.name}}
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```